# Copy Rows Based On Multiple Criteria from one Worksheet to Another VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy rows from Inventory sheet to Fruit sheet, but the codes below keeps copy and pasting in the same sheet. I have no idea how to change this. Can someone help me please? thanks in advance for any help!!

```
Sub FruitBasket()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim strFruit() As String
Dim intFruitMax As Integer


intFruitMax = 3
ReDim strFruit(1 To intFruitMax)


strFruit(1) = "Fruit 2"
strFruit(2) = "Fruit 5"
strFruit(3) = "Fruit 18"

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each rngCell In Range("A2:A" & lngLstRow)
    For i = 1 To intFruitMax
        If strFruit(i) = rngCell.Value Then
            rngCell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Inventory").Select
            Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Sheets("Fruit").Select
        End If
    Next i
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate method using autofilter to avoid having a loop.  Commented for clarity:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim aFruit() As String

    Set wsData = Sheets("Inventory")    'Copying FROM this worksheet (it contains your data)
    Set wsDest = Sheets("Fruit")        'Copying TO this worksheet (it is your destination)

    'Populate your array of values to filter for
    ReDim aFruit(1 To 3)
    aFruit(1) = "Fruit 2"
    aFruit(2) = "Fruit 5"
    aFruit(3) = "Fruit 18"

    With wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, aFruit, xlFilterValues   'Filter using the array, this avoids having to do a loop

        'Copy the filtered data (except the header row) and paste it as values
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy
        wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False     'Remove the CutCopy border
        .AutoFilter     'Remove the filter
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: To enhance a beautiful solution just a little, there should be placed a check for visible rows after filtering. And... as per OP's code, `wsDest` should be set to "Inventory" and `wsData` to "Fruit"...

Comment: hello tigeravatar, where to put an alert message: not found, if no items are found. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub FruitBasket()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim strFruit() As String
Dim intFruitMax As Integer
Dim tWs As Worksheet

intFruitMax = 3
ReDim strFruit(1 To intFruitMax)

Set tWs = Sheets("Inventory")
strFruit(1) = "Fruit 2"
strFruit(2) = "Fruit 5"
strFruit(3) = "Fruit 18"

With Sheets("Fruit")

    lngLstRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    For Each rngCell In .Range("A2:A" & lngLstRow)
        For i = 1 To intFruitMax
            If strFruit(i) = rngCell.Value Then
                tWs.Rows(tWs.Range("A" & tWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = .Rows(rngCell.Row).Value
            End If
        Next i
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

When using multiple sheets it is important to qualify all ranges to their respective sheet.   I have done this with the With Block and directly with the ranges.

Also when only posting values it is quicker to simple assign the values directly instead of copy/paste.

Also, avoid using `.Select` or `.Activate` it will slow down the code.

I also set a worksheet variable to the target sheet so the long line is a little shorter.

Comment: hello scott,  i got this messages: Runtime Error 1004  Application-defined or Object-defined error.   thx